# Is there a way/workaround on incrementing ints in java8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have the following method which performs a tree traversal and does some actions:

```
public int method(){
    int retVal;
    Tree t;
    //initialization of t
    t.accept(() -> ++retVal)); //error, variable is not 
                               //effectively final
    return retVal;
 }
```

where

```
public interface Visitor{
    public void visitNode();
}

public interface Tree{
     /**
      * Traverses this tree and perform some action in each node
      */
    public void accept(Visitor v); 

    //other methods omitted
}
```

Is there a way to workaround this?

Comment: Sure; use an `AtomicInteger` or some other mutable holder.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yes, I thought about it, but wouldn't it introduce some unnecesary synchornization traffic and cause execution CAS instructions?

Comment: Yes.  If that's a concern for you, use some other mutable holder -- even an `int[1]` would do.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Actually, got it, thaanks much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There aren't any that don't involve passing in an object instead of a local variable. However, you can do any of the following:

1. Use an `AtomicInteger`
2. Use an `int[1]`
3. (if appropriate) Move the `int` to be an instance field

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest creating a reuable, well-named class.

```
public final class CountVisitor implements Visitor {
    private int count;
    @Override
    public void visitNode() {
        this.count++;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return this.count;
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
public int method(){
    CountVisitor counter;
    Tree t;
    t.accept(counter);
    return counter.getCount();
}
```

As already said, it's reusable, and the name helps documenting the purpose.